# Can't connect to test server. "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ubuntu, webserver

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to run test server by `python3 manage.py runserver`. I got information that everything went smoothly:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 15 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly 
until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, 
sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

January 28, 2019 - 19:15:50
Django version 2.1.5, using settings 'mytestsite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Still when I try to connect to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` from Chrome browser I got the information that website is unreachable. My firewall configuration on Ubuntu:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
8000                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    127.0.0.1
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

What else might be wrong? It's my first setup. Thanks for help.

Comment: Is this all from your local server or are you running the server on another machine or, for example, on a docker instance?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to run it on external server so probably that's the reason.. I thought it's somehow possible to connect from the local machine.